# Solr: @Dynamic field not working with select query

Tags: spring-boot, solr, spring-data

I had Solr document as below :

```
@SolrDocument(collection = "test-core")
public class TestCore {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private Integer id;

    @Indexed(name = "name", type = "string")
    private String name;

    @Dynamic
    @Field("mappedField_*")
    private Map<String, String> mappedFieldValues;
}
```

Its saving records successfully in solr as shown in below snapshot :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1554871478940"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"123",
        "name":["Test name"],
        "mappedField_firstName":["vishal"],
        "mappedField_lastName":["rana"],
        "_version_":1630400697277087744}]
  }}
```

Now when I tried to find this record by id by below query :

```
Optional<TestCore> optional = testCoreRepo.findById(123);
```

Its not working, may be because of this @Dynamic fields are present there. That error log is as below :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Incompartible types found. Expected class java.lang.String for mappedFieldValues with name mappedField_*, but found class java.util.ArrayList; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompartible types found. Expected class java.lang.String for mappedFieldValues with name mappedField_*, but found class java.util.ArrayList
```

I tried to solve this whole day but didn't found any solution.
Please guide for the better solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After tried many things. I got it working now, and I think may be it can be helpful to other. 
I changes @Dynamic field datatype as below

```
@Dynamic
@Field("mappedField_*")
private Map<String, List<String>> mappedFieldValues;
```

By change this map value from String to List its working now.